# firebase serve 404 on all routes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've recently introduced firebase functions to a project of mine. The feedback loop to deploy the functions every time I want to test a change is killing my workflow.

I noticed that I can run my functions locally using `firebase serve --only functions`. I've tried this on my main project, on a clean project, and even by cloning the functions-samples repo and running `firebase serve --only functions` in this folder https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/quickstarts/big-ben.

In all cases, the console outputs a url for each function that it finds in my functions folder. Each link looks something like this: `http://localhost:5000/functions-demo-3e1a4/us-central1/app`.

But when I try to hit that route, it just returns a 404. There are always valid `functions.https.onRequest` exports correlating to the routes, so it's definitely interpreting the code correctly on startup. But it seems like when I try and consume it, it can't find the routes anymore.

I've tried changing to different node versions (8.10, 6.17, 11.2) and each time I cleaned out the node_modules folder in the `functions` folder of the project I'm testing on before installing it again. It always ends with 404s when I try to consume the routes.

In short: `firebase serve --only functions` seems to interpret the functions correctly when it starts up, but all the routes resolve to a 404.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's not really possible to say what's going wrong.  Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson, thanks but I figured out that it was because I had something else running on port `5000`, the same port used as the `supervisorPort` in `firebase-tools`. It didn't give me an error on startup though. I tried to look through the code to see if I can do a PR to fix it, but gave up after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! It turns out I was running something else on port `5000` (the default port). It didn't give an error when I ran `firebase serve --only functions` so I assumed that the port was fine.

When I ran it on a different port `firebase serve --only functions --port=9000`, it worked - I can hit my function routes and get the correct results.